# Get list of custom dimensions names with GA API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, request, metadata

How to **get a list of custom dimensions** from Google Analytics API (v3)?

I have setup a custom dimension named "Foo" in analytics console.

I have used GA [Metadata API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/reference/metadata/columns/list) to retrieve all the columns, but I just did not find any item amongst that holds "Foo" in any way.

Did anybody retrieve such a **custom dimension column names** list ever?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a list of **Custom Dimensions** via API is (as of yet) NO available, unfortunately.

Comment: I can fetch reports of custom dimensions, it is quiet possible. Although, I couldn't get a list of available dimensions.

Comment: :) Geri, sure you can run reports using custom dimensions, however it's not (still) possible to get a list of custom dimensions defined in GA account.

Comment: Yap, just the wording of the answer could be misleading.